# How can I reuse a variable derived from a for-loop in a method on a different method in the same class?

Tags: ios, swift, class, ios-ui-automation

**Background:** I'm working on automating a calendar app which contains a UICollectionView with many cells representing time slots.
I have a CalendarView class with the Login class as its super class. This CalendarView class contains all the methods I use in the calendar so that my tests look something like this

```
func testMakeAppointment() {
    CalendarView()
        .moveToCorrectSchedule()
        .findEmptyCalendarCell()
        .tapNewAppointmentCell()
        .enterRegAppointmentInfo()
        .tapLatestAppointment()
```

On my `findEmptyCalendarCell()` I use a for-loop to locate the first available cell that's hittable on the calendar. The method looks like this:

```
func findEmptyCalendarCell() ->CalendarView {
    let partialCellPath = XCUIApplication().collectionViews.childrenMatchingType(.Other)
    let start: UInt = 10
    let totalAmountOfCells = partialCellPath.count
    for i in start...totalAmountOfCells {
        if partialCellPath.elementBoundByIndex(i).otherElements["CalendarCell"].exists == true {
            if partialCellPath.elementBoundByIndex(i).otherElements["CalendarCell"].hittable == true {
                partialCellPath.elementBoundByIndex(i).otherElements["CalendarCell"].tap()
            xctc.pauseForSeconds(1)
            }
        }
    }

    return CalendarView()
}
```

On the two following methods, I tap the cell I found and enter the appointment information and create the appointment.

**Problem:** Up to this point everything is good. However, I now need to tap the appointment I just created in order to assert the appointment object now exists on the calendar.  (This would be done under the `tapLatestAppointment()` method.

If I could somehow reuse the `i` variable from the for-loop in `findEmptyCalendarCell()` to tap the same cell I used to create the appointment, that would be great. But unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to save this variable for later use.

Could anyone please help me find a possible solution to this? I tried making `i` a class variable of type UInt?, but since I return a new instance of CalendarView() after each method, this value is always `nil` :(

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Certainly a far better model would be if a new `CalendarView` were not returned after each method call, but if you want to avoid rewriting your implementation you could just make `i` a global variable, declared outside any class. Alternatively you could create a class just for this purpose that would have a static property.

In a `for` loop, the value will only be available inside the loop. If this were not the case we would have thousands of variables floating around at every namespace for apps that used a lot of `for`s, memory would get hammered, and it would be a pain to code, quite frankly.

But based on your code what you really want is not a way to refer to `i`, which is changing on each `for` iteration, but a way to identify the last tapped index.

So how about something like:

```
func findEmptyCalendarCell() ->CalendarView {
    let partialCellPath = XCUIApplication().collectionViews.childrenMatchingType(.Other)
    let start: UInt = 10
    let totalAmountOfCells = partialCellPath.count
    for i in start...totalAmountOfCells {
        if partialCellPath.elementBoundByIndex(i).otherElements["CalendarCell"].exists == true {
            if partialCellPath.elementBoundByIndex(i).otherElements["CalendarCell"].hittable == true {
                partialCellPath.elementBoundByIndex(i).otherElements["CalendarCell"].tap()
                selectedIndex = i  // See below
                xctc.pauseForSeconds(1)
            }
        }
    }

    return CalendarView()
}
```

Where `selectedIndex` would be defined at a global scope, at any file within your module and outside of any brackets, like so:

```
var selectedIndex: Int? = nil
```

Then under any situation where you want the selected index to go back to `nil`, just set it as such:

```
selectedIndex = nil
```

In `tapLatestAppointment`, then, you would need to fall back when `selectedIndex` is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but just out of curiosity, how could I make it so I don't create new instances of CalendarView() and yet still keep the test cases as clean as the the one above?

Comment: I don't have a solution for that since I don't know your complete implementation, but if you're just doing this for tests (something that didn't click for me the first time), then it's probably fine.

Comment: As I had expected, using a global variable this way always returns nil. I suspect it's because the value of selectedIndex goes back to nil when I start a new instance of CalendarView().

Comment: If you declared `selectedIndex` at a truly global level, outside of any class or object whatsoever, and the only place you set it is inside `findEmptyCalendarCell`, then how would it go back to `nil`?

Comment: Mr. Matthew Seaman, you're absolutely right. I was thinking global scope as of the global scope of the class. Thank you so much for your help :)